# How to skip forward/backward a word at a time when editing postgres command in psql?

Tags: postgresql, keyboard, psql

In most command line interface "cli" programs the `Option-arrow` key combinations allows one to move forwards/backwards a word at a time.  But in `psql` both `Option-arrow` and `Control-Arrow` actually insert non printable control characters that *corrupt* the command.  In addition in most `CLI` programs hitting `CTL-A` goes to the beginning of the command and `CTL-E` goes to the end of the command. But in `psql` those combinations do not have any effect.

Navigating a single character at a time is simply too slow: I can not imagine this were an unsolved problem. What is the configuration needed to get one of those key combinations to skip forward/backward by words not characters?

Comment: AFAIK `psql` uses `readline` (or `libedit` if `readline` is not available) for line editing purposes. It should work the same as most other CLI tools out of the box. You might want to check you don't have some special configuration in eg `~/.inputrc`. You might also have the `--no-readline` flag set when starting `psql` (or more likely its short version `-n`).

Comment: @Marth   You are correct: I have `set editing-mode vi `  in `~/.inputrc` and that is corrupting the `readline` . Please create an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an answer containing the response in the comment by by @Marth.  The `~/.inputrc` *does* cause the issue.

```
# want vi to be the default editor for readline                      
set editing-mode vi                                            

$if mode=vi                
    # normal mode                           
    set keymap vi-command                                 
    set keymap vi-insert 
    "\C-n": backward-kill-word
    "\C-p": history-search-backward
$endif
```

I have completely removed the `~/.inputrc` now.